# Force Bundler to install gems supported by the local Ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, activesupport

Is there a way of installing the latest supported version of a dependency without specifying it?

I'm having issues with the [activesupport](https://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport/versions/5.0.0) gem. The latest version (5.0.0.1) supports Ruby >= 2.2.2. If I'm specifying that I require the gem like this `'~> 4.2'` Bundler will try to install version 5 even if I'm on Ruby 2.0. Specifying the exact version `4.2.7.1` or setting a maximum `'~> 4.2', '< 5'` works, except when using the gem with Rails 5.

Is there a way to manage gem versions based on the current Ruby version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the new version of Bundler will do this for you automatically.
I found [this comment](https://github.com/bundler/bundler-features/issues/120#issuecomment-214514847) from André Arko that mentions this is already included in the latest RC version.

I specified `Ruby '2.0'` in my Gemfile, installed Bundler with `gem install bundler --pre` (it installed bundler-1.13.0.rc.2) and `bundle install` successfully installed activesupport 4.2.7.1.

With Bundler 1.12.5 I was getting the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing activesupport (5.0.0.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that while a bit more manual, you can also include logic in your Gemfiles:

```
if RUBY_VERSION <  "2.2.2"
  gem "activesupport", "4.2.7.1"
else
  gem "activesupport", "5.0.0.1"  
end
```

Comment: This is a gem dependency, so it must be put in the gemspec.